# Link WordPress Logo with Index.PHP

Tags: css, wordpress, image, hyperlink

So I just added a Logo to the WordPress Theme I am working with, and I added the Logo with the following CSS:

```
#header {
    background-image: url(img/logo.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 140px;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
```

My Question is, how can I turn that Image into a Link linking to the Index of my WordPress Theme? I know the solution for simple HTML and CSS but I've never done something like that with WordPress...

Comment: You can't. To make it linkable you have to add it with the `<img>` tag.

Comment: Is this a new theme you are working on, or a default Wordpress theme? The default wordpress themes already link back to the index

Comment: It is a theme written by myself, because the site is going to be done for a customer...

Comment: An example for an image tag? Seriously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want take a look at how the default Wordpress themes (twentyeleven, twentytwelve...) accomplish this. These themes are split up into several files that each cover certain parts of the website. The header image, links, navigation usually go into the `header.php` file somewhere.

This is how the Twenty Twelve theme links back to home in its `header.php`:

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
    <img ... />
</a>
```

From the looks of your code you have an element with `class="header"` somewhere, you can link it like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
    <div id="header">Header text?</div>
</a>
```

I suggest you read the official [Wordpress documentation on developing themes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development), it covers the basics. And you should read up on some basic HTML and CSS tutorials maybe, or learn from the existing themes.

Comment: Thanks for your awnser, it really helped out. 
As I mentioned it above I dont have a problem working with pure HTML and CSS but I just started working with WordPress and I am right now not that into the working process of it.